# Hold'em Manager for Mac alternative?

Tags: poker-tools, holdem-manager

Does anyone know any poker analysis tool which can be used on Mac OS?
Hold'em Manager 2 works only on Windows, and I don't want to use any wine programs.

Comment: Not sure if the question is suitable since it is probably opinion based. I found [this source](http://www.pokersoftware.com/categories/mac-poker.html) which would suggest Poker Tracker 4 is a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a very nice piece of software called [PokerTracker](https://www.pokertracker.com/)
It does everything I needed, and the first month of trial is for free.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main options for poker analysis on Mac OS X:

- [Poker Copilot](https://pokercopilot.com/)
- [PokerTracker](http://pokertracker.com)

There are some other products but they all seem to have been abandoned or have a limited feature set.

(Disclaimer: my company makes one of the two products I listed).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's lucky/unusual that HoldemManager and PokerTracker have stuck around as long as they have they must be serious labors of love because if you think about it they really messed up their monetization strategy making it a one-off purchase until they spend 1-2 years full on coding a new version to charge ppl for again. I just don't think there's any way the creators of either software could solely support themselves from that alone.